# Why does php allow invalid return type declerations it knows it can't allow?

Tags: php, php-internals

As far as I can tell php has the ability to prevent a return type from being declared where it knows it's problematic.

```
class Foo {
    public function __clone(): Baz {
        return new Baz;
    }
}

class Baz {

}

$foo = new Foo;
$newFoo = clone $foo;
```

This results in a `Fatal error: Clone method Foo::__clone() cannot declare a return type`, which is perfectly sensible.

But then why would php allow things like this:

```
class Foo {
    public function __toString(): float {
        return "WAT!?!";
    }
}

echo new Foo;
```

This results in

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Foo::__toString() must be of the type float, string returned

Which doesn't make sense, because were you to try and return a float:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Method Foo::__toString() must return a string value

Wouldn't it make more sense for php to prevent the declared return type of these types of methods rather than give those dubious errors? If not, what is the underlying reason behind this internally? Is there some mechanical barricade that prevents php from doing this where it can do it in cases like **clone**?

Comment: You could always file a bug report for this slightly off error handling that's totally not worth fixing.

Comment: Yes, it would make more sense. It's actually a [known issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69718) and there's a [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/4177) open to get it fixed (which has some issues that haven't been resolved yet).

Comment: @rickdenhaan good to know. I think maybe you should submit that as the official answer. I don't really see a better one.

Comment: @emptyheap I'm actually more inclined to close this as off-topic. It's an interesting question, but it's more about how php works internally and not about a specific coding problem.

Comment: Are php internals offtopic at StackOverflow? If so where should I post the question?

Comment: It's not necessarily off-topic, but it's also not really "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" since it's not something that's wrong with your code (other than "just don't do that") but with the inner workings of the language itself. So in my opinion, this particular question is better suited for the PHP [bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net) or the internals [mailing list](https://www.php.net/mailing-lists.php). But I'm sure there are others who disagree with me :)

Comment: That's something that is either a bug or a hard-to-understand feature which you didn't read the documentation for. For that reason, this question belongs in the PHP bug tracker, where it can be found and tracked, not here. I'm against using SO as bug dump for projects that have their own issue tracker. I admit that this isn't a clear case though. If this had been worded slightly different, it might have looked different.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: Supporting type inferences on magic methods breaks backwards compatibility.**

Example: what does this code output?

```
$foo = new Foo;
$bar = $foo->__construct();
echo get_class($bar);
```

If you said `Foo`, you are incorrect: it's [`Bar`](https://3v4l.org/blFGn).

---

PHP has a long, complicated evolution of its return type handling.

- Before PHP 7.0, return type hints were a parse error.
- In PHP 7.0, we got return type declarations with very simple rules ([RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types)), and after perhaps the most contentious internal debate ever, we got strict types ([RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5)).
- PHP limped along with some oddities in co- and contra-variance until PHP 7.4, where we got many of these sorted ([RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/covariant-returns-and-contravariant-parameters)).

The behavior of today reflects this organic growth, warts and all.

You indicate that the `__clone()` behavior is sensible, then compare that to the apparently non-sensical `__toString()` behavior. I challenge that *neither* of them are sensible, under any rational expectation of type inference.

Here's the [`__clone`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_compile.c#L6706) engine code:

```
6642     if (ce->clone) {                                                          
6643         if (ce->clone->common.fn_flags & ZEND_ACC_STATIC) {                   
6644             zend_error_noreturn(E_COMPILE_ERROR, "Clone method %s::%s() cannot be static",
6645                 ZSTR_VAL(ce->name), ZSTR_VAL(ce->clone->common.function_name));
6646         } else if (ce->clone->common.fn_flags & ZEND_ACC_HAS_RETURN_TYPE) {   
6647             zend_error_noreturn(E_COMPILE_ERROR,                              
6648                 "Clone method %s::%s() cannot declare a return type",         
6649                 ZSTR_VAL(ce->name), ZSTR_VAL(ce->clone->common.function_name));
6650         }                                                                     
6651     }
```

Pay careful attention to that wording (emphasis mine):

> **Clone method** ... **cannot declare a return type**

`__clone()` gave you an error not because the types were *different*, but because *you gave a type at all*! This also is a [compile error](https://3v4l.org/RGkLS):

```
class Foo {
    public function __clone(): Foo {
        return new Foo;
    }
}
```

"Why?!", you scream.

I believe there are two reasons:

1. Internals is beholden to a high-bar of backwards compatibility maintenance.
2. Incremental improvement comes slowly, each improvement building on earlier ones.

Let's talk about #1. Consider [this code](https://3v4l.org/cOOCa), which is valid all the way back to PHP 4.0:

```
<?php
class Amount {
    var $amount;
}
class TaxedAmount extends Amount {
    var $rate;
    function __toString() {
        return $this->amount * $this->rate;
    }
}
$item = new TaxedAmount;
$item->amount = 242.0;
$item->rate = 1.13;
echo "You owe me $" . $item->__toString() . " for this answer.";
```

Some poor soul used `__toString` as their own method, in a perfectly reasonable way. Now preserving its behavior is a top priority, so we can't make changes to the engine that break this code. That's the motivation for `strict_types` declaration: allowing opt-in changes to parser behavior so as to keep old behavior going while still adding new behavior.

You might ask: why don't we just fix this when `declare(strict_types=1)` is on? Well, because [this code](https://3v4l.org/LtUv0) is perfectly valid in strict types mode, too! It even makes [sense](https://3v4l.org/AbObF):

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

class Amount {
    var $amount;
}
class TaxedAmount extends Amount {
    var $rate;
    function __toString(): float {
        return $this->amount * $this->rate;
    }
}
$item = new TaxedAmount;
$item->amount = 242.0;
$item->rate = 1.13;
echo "You owe me $" . $item->__toString() . " for this answer.";
```

Nothing about this code smells. It's valid PHP code. If the method were called `getTotalAmount` instead of `__toString`, no one would bat an eye. The only odd part: the method name is "reserved".

So the engine can neither (a) enforce `__toString` returns a string type nor (b) prevent you from setting your own return type. Because to do either would violate backwards compatibility.

What we could do, however, is implement a new affirmative opt-in that says these methods aren't directly callable. Once we do that, then we can add type inference to them. Hypothetically:

```
<?php declare(strict_magic=1);

class Person {
    function __construct(): Person {
    }
    function __toString(): string {
    }
    // ... other magic
}

(new Person)->__construct(); // Fatal Error: cannot call magic method on strict_magic object
```

And this is point #2: once we have a way to protect backwards compatibility, we can add a way to enforce types on magic methods.

In summary, `__construct`, `__destruct`, `__clone`, `__toString`, etc. are both (a) functions the engine calls in certain circumstances for which it can reasonably infer types and (b) functions that - historically - can be called directly in ways that violate the reasonable type inference from (1).

This is the reason [PR 4117](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/4177) to fix [Bug #69718](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69718) is blocked.

The only way to break this stale-mate: the developer opts in to a promise that these methods cannot be called directly. Doing that frees the engine to enforce strict type inference rules.